# Making a java applet meet high security standards

Tags: java, security, browser, applet

I have a working applet and I am trying to add it to my website for my portfolio. My problem is I can't get the applet to run without adding the directory (I'm running it locally for now) to the site exception list. my applet code is as follows:

```
<applet code = "myTetris.TetrisApplet" 
        archive = "myTetris\jar.jar" 
        height = "400" width = "200">
```

I have created a jar file using IntelliJ IDEA. The manifest is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Permissions: sandbox
Application-Name: Tetris
```

I have signed the jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 7 update 51 Java Web Start applications and applets need to be signed and must have a permission set in the manifest. You have done both correctly. However, the certificate you used for code signing, was probably a so-called self signed certificate. As the identity of the signer cannot be verified, such certificates are not trusted by browsers, operating systems, and the Java Runtime. To fix this, you would either need to import your certificate into your system and trust it, or you would need to obtain (buy) a certificate that was issued by a trusted authority. Some organizations offer trusted certificates for open sources projects.